# How do I decide between injectable helper class versus a static one?

Tags: c#, oop, mvvm

Let's say my ViewModel has an IsValidEmail property and I want to extract my e-mail validation logic into separate class for re-use.

Do I make this e-mail validation class injectable or make it as a static helper class?

Would like to the hear pros and cons of both approaches.

Comment: Static classes are much more difficult to unit test. For that reason alone you might decide not to. Additionally, static classes are generally used to share state but if you just have logic there is no good reason to make it static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb to decide between static and instance is,

If you are 100% sure you don't want to behave your function/property to behave polymorphically then static would be a good fit. For example, a function that returns the value of PI (3.14) can be static as it would be a universal static constant.

Instance method/property can be overridden and can behave polymorphically (can change the behaviour during run time). If you want an overriden behaviour then static won't help because the static method cannot override as the name indicates it is static. Example: Say you want to create a function which calculates the salary of employees in an organization. Depends on employee designation salary calculation will vary. In this case, you cannot use a static function because based on the object the salary calculation varies.

In your example, email validation can be static as regardless of the object the validation would be static. One catch here the unit test you write on the parent will always trigger the validation as you can't mock static.

If you are not sure your function/property behaves polymorphically then always go for instance method/property. Only go for static if you are completely sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I make this e-mail validation class injectable or make it as a
>   static helper class?

It's a view model (OR) just a POCO class, then why can't you just instantiate it wherever needed (OR) just pass an instance of that type in whichever validation method you are needed.